# The relation between formal group $\frac{X+Y}{1-XY}$ and algebraic group $x^2+y^2=1$ with group law $*$

Tags: number-theory, power-series, tangent-line, arithmetic-geometry, formal-groups

$T(X,Y)=\frac{X+Y}{1-XY}$ is a power series which satisfies axiom of formal group.

My book reads this formal group comes from algebraic group $S: x^2+y^2=1$, with group law $*$:$(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2)=(x_1x_2-y_1y_2,x_1y_2+x_2y_1)$.

$y/x$ is local parameter at $(1,0)$, thus **expanding $*$ at origin gives formal group $T(X,Y)$.**

What does '**expanding $*$ at origin gives formal group $T(X,Y)$**' mean ?

I thought we can write $x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, y=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, but calculating $xy-yx$ does not meet with $T(x,y)$. I'm sticking with how to gain tangent like formal group $T(X,Y)$ from group law of $S$ as my book reads.

Comment: Let $(x_3,y_3)=(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2) $ and $Z_i=y_i/x_i$ then $Z_3=\frac{Z_1+Z_2}{1-Z_1Z_2}$. $Z=y/x$ is a local parameter at the identity element $(1,0)$ because we have some kind of parametrization $Z\mapsto (1/\sqrt{Z^2+1},Z/\sqrt{Z^2+1})$

Comment: Thank you for your really helpful comment. Sorry to bother, but what is your definition of local parameter here and why is  your $Z$ local parameter at $(1,0)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal group law is visible as follows. Let $(x_1,y_1)*(x_2,y_2)=:(x_3,y_3)$, which is a multiplication of points near the origin $(1,0)$. We use the local parameter (in the sense below) $z:=y/x$, which is well-defined as long as $x\neq 0$, e.g., the point $(x,y)$ is near the origin. We denote by $z_i$ the value of the parameter corresponding to the points $(x_i,y_i)\ (i=1,2,3)$. Now "expand"
$$\begin{split}
z_3&=\frac{y_3}{x_3}=\frac{x_1y_2+x_2y_1}{x_1x_2-y_1y_2}\\
&=\frac{y_2/x_2+y_1/x_1}{1-(y_1/x_1)\cdot
(y_2/x_2)}=\frac{z_1+z_2}{1-z_1z_2},
\end{split}$$
where the third equality is given by dividing both the numerator/denominator by $x_1x_2$. Thus we deduced the formal group law $z_3=T(z_1,z_2)$. This can be seen just the multiplication formula near the origin, expanded in terms of the local parameter $z$.

The terminology "local parameter" is frequently used to refer (any of) the generator of the maximal ideal of a DVR. In our case, this DVR is the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{G,e}$ at the identity $e$ in the algebraic group $G$, where $G=\mathrm{Spec}\ k[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1)$ and $e=(1,0)(=(X-1,Y))$. For example, $z=y/x$ is a local parameter by the Jacobian criterion, namely $(\partial f/\partial x)(1,0)=2\neq 0$ (I believe you are in characteristic $\neq 2$) shows that $y$ is a local parameter, and the unit $1/x$ is multiplied so that our group law becomes simple. Of course we could have used another local parameter, in which case we get another group law and a (nontrivially looking) isomorphism between formal group laws.

EDIT: We shall prove that $y$ is a uniformizer of the DVR $\mathcal{O}_{G,e}$, where $G=\mathrm{Spec}\ k[x,y]/f,\ f=x^2+y^2-1$ and $e=(1,0)$.
I think the proof of Jacobian criterion as in e.g. [Hartshorne's book Chapter I, Theorem 5.1] will be the simplest to apply. There it is proved that $m/m^2\simeq a/((f)+a^2)$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{G,e}$ and $a$ is the maximal ideal $(x-1,y)$ of $k[x,y]$.
To see $y$ is a generator of the 1-dimensional $k$-linear space $m/m^2$, it is enough to show $y\not\in (f)+a^2$. But
$$(f)+a^2=((x-1)(x+1)+y^2,(x-1)^2,(x-1)y,y^2)\subset (x-1,y^2),$$
so surely $y$ is not in this ideal. Note, here, that $a/a^2$ is a $k$-linear space with basis $x-1,y$ and in this space
$$f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)(x-1)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1,0)y\quad (\mathrm{mod}\ a^2)$$
holds by Taylor expansion. So, the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,0)\neq 0$ really corresponds to $y$ being the basis of $a/((f)+a^2)$. This is why I tend to say "by Jacobian criterion...".

Comment: We use a local parameter z = y/x near (1, 0) to "zoom in" and analyze the local behavior. Expanding the group law * in terms of z gives the formal group law T(z1, z2)/ Different local parameters would give isomorphic formal group laws (related by a change of variables)

points:
The term "local parameter" typically refers to generators of maximal ideals in DVRs, but the general notion of a local parameter (a coordinate function that lets you analyze a space) is being used here//The condition (∂f/∂x)(1, 0) ≠ 0 shows y is a local parameter, not z = y/x - but z is a local parameter

Comment: @Ayaka. Thank you for beautiful answer. Localization of $G$ at $(X-1,Y)$ is certainly DVR because $G$ is Dedekind domain thanks to Jacobi criterion, but why Jacobi criterion proves $Y$ is uniformizer ? Jacobi criterion I know only proves given curve is smooth, namely coordinate ring is Dedekind domain. You may use another Jacobi criterion, but I couldn't find it. If possible, I'll be appreciated if you could tell me what is the statement and proof of your 'Jacobi criterion'(reference is also appreciated).

Comment: And could you tell me why $x$ is unit of localization of $G$ at $(X-1,Y)$ ?

Comment: Since $X$ is not in the maximal ideal $(X-1,Y)$, it becomes a unit in the local ring. For the Jacobian criterion, I'll edit the answer later.

Comment: I have added some explanation of the Jacobian criterion. I'm happy to be of your help @topology.

Comment: @Ayaka Thank you so much. I really appreciate your really helpful, detailed, kind, beautiful  answer.